# Windows Server 2008 - Smart Card service is down

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, smartcard

I'm getting this weird error when trying to work with a SmartCard on an ec2 machine running Windows Server 2008.

I'm using AnywhereUSB to connect my physical smart-card reader to the remote machine. The device itself seems to be recognized fine by the OS, but when I try to access it, I'm getting this error.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the status of the CNG Key Isolation service on that machine, and if it is not started, can you start it and see if that helps?

Comment: @RyanRies, the Smart Card service is running (I edited with a screenshot). What's the CNG Key Isolation service ? What should I look for?

Comment: I like the green arrow checkmark things you use in your screenshots. There is a Windows Service named CNG Key Isolation. It's integral in many private key encryption/decryption operations.

Comment: Making it easier for you to make it easier for me :) Ok so I went ahead and started "CNG Key Isolation" service (it's indeed configured for Manual startup). But, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Are those screenshots from the server or the client? it may be that the smart card service on the host you're connecting from is down.